# Fast way to make sure string does not contain specific characters

Tags: c#, string, performance, validation

I want to make sure that C# string does not contain specific characters.

I am using `string.IndexOfAny(char[])`, in my opinion Regex would be slower in this task. Is there a better way to accomplish this? Speed is critical in my application.

Comment: Implement and then benchmark. If neither solution is fast enough, think about a different one.

Comment: You generally can assume that all built-in string methods are highly optimized out of the box. So I don't think there's a faster method...

Comment: Have you run any performance tests?  Off the top of my head I'd say `IndexOfAny` would be faster than RegEx as it is *specifically doing what you want it to do*.

Comment: "in my opinion Regex would be slower in this task" That's a pretty baseless opinion, unless it is based on a benchmark.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ran a quick benchmark on `IndexOf` vs `IndexOfAny` vs `Regex` vs `Hashset`.
500 word lorem ipsum haystack, with two character needle.
Tested with both needles in haystack, one in haystack, neither in haystack.

```
    private long TestIndexOf(string haystack, char[] needles)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch sw = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
        sw.Start();
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
        {
            int x = haystack.IndexOfAny(needles);
        }
        sw.Stop();

        return sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;
    }

    private long TestRegex(string haystack, char[] needles)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch sw = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
        sw.Start();
        Regex regex = new Regex(string.Join("|", needles));
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
        {
            Match m = regex.Match(haystack);
        }
        sw.Stop();

        return sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;
    }

    private long TestIndexOf(string haystack, char[] needles)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch sw = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
        sw.Start();
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
        {
            int x = haystack.IndexOf(needles[0]);
        }
        sw.Stop();

        return sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;
    }

    private long TestHashset(string haystack, char[] needles)
    {
        HashSet<char> specificChars = new HashSet<char>(needles.ToList());
        System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch sw = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
        sw.Start();
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
        {
            bool notContainsSpecificChars = !haystack.Any(specificChars.Contains);
        }
        sw.Stop();

        return sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;
    }
```

Result for 1,000,000 iterations:

> Index of : 28/2718/2711
>   Index of Any : 153/141/17561
>   Regex of : 1068/1102/92324
>   Hashset : 939/891/111702

Notes:

- Smaller haystack improves performance.
- Larger needle set increases regex performance.
- Larger needle set reduces indexofany performance.
- If needle is not in haystack all methods degrade in performance

Overall, `regex` is slower then `indexofany` by upto 10x depending on the haystack and needle sizes.

Comment: A benchmark of `IndexOf()` besides of `IndexOfAny()` (as suggested by @stefano m and @Steve Ruble in their answers) would be interesting too.

Comment: The indexof test only checks for one needle not all of them

Answer (score 2):

You could use this concise and efficient LINQ query:

```
HashSet<char> specificChars = new HashSet<char>{ 'a', 'b', 'c'};
bool notContainsSpecificChars = !"test".Any(specificChars.Contains); // true
```

I have used a `HashSet<char>` since it is efficient for lookups, duplicates aren't allowed.

if you have an array as input you could use the [constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb301504%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to create a `HashSet` from it:

```
char[] chars = new[] { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'c' };
specificChars = new HashSet<char>(chars); // c is removed since it was a duplicate
```

Another approach without `HashSet` is using `Enumerable.Intersect` + `Enumerable.Any`:

```
bool notContainsSpecificChars = !"test".Intersect(chars).Any();
```

Answer (score 0):

if you must find one char only, it woulb be better call method IndexOf(singleChar) or IndexOf(singleChar, startIndex, charCount) instead.

Of cuorse Regex would be much more computational expensive!

Answer (score 0):

`String.IndexOfAny(char[])` is implemented in the CLR itself and `String.IndexOf` uses an extern call, so they're both pretty fast. Either will be much faster than using a regex.

Whether `IndexOf` is better than `IndexOfAny` depends on how many characters you're expecting to be checking for. Based on some really rough benchmarking, it looks like `IndexOf` performs better (by a tiny amount) for 2 or fewer characters, but `IndexOfAny` is better for 3 or more. The difference is minuscule, though - the advantage of using `IndexOfAny` may be overwhelmed by the cost of allocating the array of characters.